# A hereditarily Lindelöf, minimal KC-space is sequential

Tags: general-topology, compactness

**A space is said to have the finite derived set property if each infinite subset $A ⊂ X$ contains an infinite subset with only finitely many accumulation points in X.**

> **A hereditarily Lindelöf, minimal KC-space is sequential**.

**Proof:** Suppose that $(X, τ)$ is a hereditarily Lindelöf minimal $KC$-space. suppose that $A ⊂ X$ is not closed and hence not compact. Since $X$ is hereditarily
Lindelöf, $A$ is not countably compact and hence we can find a countable discrete subset
$D = \{x_n : n ∈ ω \} ⊆ A$ which is closed in $A$; that is to say, all of the accumulation points
of $D$ lie outside of $A$.we know that, $X$ has the $FDS$-property, and so there is some
countably infinite set $E ⊆ D$ with only a finite number of accumulation points in $X$, all of
which lie in $cl(A) - A$. Thus $cl(E)$ is a countable, compact KC-space and ,we know that every countably KC is sequentialy compact, so $cl(E)$ is sequential; thus there is a sequence in E converging out of E and
hence out of $A$.

> I would like to know:
>
> **1: Why** is $D$ discrete subset?
>    is $D$ closed subset, due to there is no  accumulation points in $D$?
>
> **2: Why**  is there a sequence in E converging **out of E**  and hence **out of A**?( I mean $cl(E)$ is sequential, but there is a sequence in E converging out of E)

Comment: A duplicate. Really? They don't even concern the same proof. And don't ask identical questions.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a partial answer, but I must admit that I'm having trouble parsing the grammar in the last sentence of your proof. Perhaps there was a transcription mistake, or perhaps you've simply got results I've never seen before, but either way, it doesn't make sense to me. What is the source of this proof? If I knew that, I could take a look, and perhaps be better equipped to clear up your confusion.

I will continue to think on it, though, and add to my answer if I come up with anything.

---

Under the assumption of Countable Choice, it can be shown that a $T_1$ space is countably-compact if and only if it has no countably-infinite closed subset which is discrete in the subspace topology (equivalently, no countably-infinite subset without accumulation points). A $KC$ space is hereditarily $T_1,$ so $A$ is $T_1$. Since $A$ is Lindelöf and non-compact, then it is not countably-compact, and so has a countably-infinite closed subset $D$ that is discrete as a subspace of $A$. Then $D$ has no accumulation points in $A$, for if such a point existed, it would be an element of $D$ (since $D$ is closed) that is not isolated in $D$, which is not possible since $D$ is discrete as a subspace of $A$.

As remarked in the proof, $D$ may well have accumulation points in $X$ (that is, $D$ need not be closed in $X$), but such points lie outside of $A$--and in particular, lie in $\operatorname{cl}(A)\setminus A$.